# How to unload a Mathematica package?

Tags: packages

I am using a publicly available Mathematica package on [this](https://github.com/ianhinder/EccentricIMR) page and is loaded in Mathematica by the command

> << EccentricIMR`;

How do I unload this package? I don't want to use 'Quit' or 'Exit' since I lose all the definitions.

Why do I want to do this? I have two very similar packages with a lot of functions whose names coincide when both the packages are loaded at once. I plan to unload one before I load the other.

Comment: Why do you need to unload the package?

Comment: Fyi, This has been discussed many times. Examples: [how-to-unload-automatically-loaded-packages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1487/how-to-unload-automatically-loaded-packages) and [clearing-out-a-package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149453/clearing-out-a-package) and ["unload" a package](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/Oct/msg00821.html) and [Unloading packages](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2002/Jan/msg00383.html)

Comment: From your question and self-answer we can tell this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); be aware for future questions that including the chain of choices that lead up to the question is generally a good idea.

Answer (score 14):

Depending on your definition of "unload", it may be enough to remove the package's contexts from `$ContextPath`.

The symbols will still exist in your kernel, but you'd only run into them by using their full names including the context.

Answer (score 9):

Easiest and most secure method is restarting the kernel with `Exit`.

You can also try

```
names = Join[ Names["EccentricIMR`*"] , Names["EccentricIMR`*`*"];
ClearAll /@ names
Remove /@ names
```

But there is not guarantee that this removes all symbols. E.g., symbols in deeper hidden contexts are neither cleared nor removed this way. Also `Protected` symbols cannot be removed this way.

Comment: Exit and Quit will erase all the definitions. I don't want that.

Answer (score -1):

I found a hack. The purpose of unloading the package was to avoid conflicts. There is a way to do that. Every package file begins with the statement of the Context. See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BeginPackage.html?view=all).

```
BeginPackage["square`"];
```

Here, 'square' is the context. Since we have two similar packages containing functions with the common names, what we first have to do is to keep the context names different. For example, if the first package file begins with

```
BeginPackage["square`"];
```

then the second package must begin differently, say

```
BeginPackage["square2`"];
```

So now, we have created two different contexts which will help us delineate between the two packages. Let's say there is a function with the common name 'func' in both the packages. Here is how I will use func

```
square`func[....]
square2`func[....]
```

The first (second) line invokes the func function from the first (second) package.

Comment: Erm. Yes, that is the way how contexts work; definitely not a hack. Btw., you missed to tell us that you have control over the package source.

Comment: Sorry but this has nothing to do with 'unloading'. This could be the answer to the question how packages/contexts work. Or did I miss the point?

Comment: Yeah, I did not unload the package. But it serves my purpose.